# operation overloading operator++()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class Point{
private:
    int xpos, ypos;
public:
    Point(int x=0, int y=0) : xpos(x), ypos(y) { }
    void showPosition() const {
        cout<<"["<<xpos<<", "<<ypos<<"]"<<endl;
    } 
    Point& operator++(){  //Point operator++()
        xpos+=1;
        ypos+=1;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

For operator++() I know Point& is the right return type, but I don't get why Point return type would not also work.

```
    Point operator++(){ 
        xpos+=1;
        ypos+=1;
        return *this;
    }
```

when I use this to perform

```
Point pos(1,3);
++(++pos);
```

I get

```
[2,4]
```

not

```
[3,5] //which is what I should be getting.
```

I think operator++() without the reference should still give the same result, as it would implicitly call its copy constructor, so albeit slower, I think it should give the same result.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You obviously know that a copy of `pos` is returned by the first operation, so why do you think invoking `pos.showPosition()` afterwards is going to show the result of both operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `++` returns a copy, then the second `++` in `++(++pos)` calls `operator++` on the copy returned by the first `++`, not on the original `pos`. Thus the original `pos` is only incremented once.

Answer (score 0):

```
Point& operator++()
```

should return by reference to non-const so as to let us do ,

```
Point p;
++++p;
```

Had it returned `Point`, you would be trying to modify the temporary which is not the behavior you want.